# How to erase all files from namenode?

Tags: java, hadoop

I have formatted the namenode using following commands:

```
sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode stop
rm -rf /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/name
hadoop namenode -format
sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start
```

But when after the formatting when I try to browse the namenode again it shows me the files. Why isn't formatting removing all the files?

Last few lines of `hadoop namenode -format` output:

```
14/09/22 03:25:14 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 889 MB = 273.1 KB
14/09/22 03:25:14 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
14/09/22 03:25:14 INFO namenode.AclConfigFlag: ACLs enabled? false
Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/cloudera/dfs/name ? (Y or N) Y
14/09/22 03:25:16 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-1124575958-0.0.0.0-1411381516246
14/09/22 03:25:16 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/cloudera/dfs/name has been successfully formatted.
14/09/22 03:25:16 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
14/09/22 03:25:16 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
14/09/22 03:25:16 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at quickstart.cloudera/0.0.0.0
************************************************************/
```

After the formatting it still shows me the previous files:

```
[cloudera@quickstart name]$ hadoop fs -ls /
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup       9051 2014-09-22 02:50 /notice.html
drwxr-xr-x   - solr     solr                0 2014-09-19 02:30 /solr
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs     supergroup          0 2014-09-19 02:26 /user
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the datanode to delete all files on the HDFS, which is done in a way similar to namenode,

`hadoop datanode -format` or `hdfs datanode -format` or `hdfs hadoop datanode` -format according to your hadoop version.

Comment: I'm not sure that is the case. `hadoop datanode --help` shows that `-format` is not a valid option for datanode. Namenode stores the filesystem. The actual data does not need to be erased to remove file system entries.

Comment: what is your hadoop version

Comment: `Hadoop 2.3.0-cdh5.1.0`

Comment: you can also delete the directory of datanode set in the hdfs-site.xml and then format the namenode.